# Splitting a list into two lists equal in length in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am writing a predicate in Prolog to divide a list into two equal in length lists. For example :

```
div([1,2,3,4] , X , Y).
X = [1,2].
Y = [3,4].
```

That's my code but it's not working :

```
div(L , L1 , L):- length(L) == length(L1).
div([ H | T ] , [ H | T1] , L2):- div(T , T1 , L2).
```

Comment: Once you fix the problem with `length/2` as @larsmans pointed out, your solution still appears to try and construct the first half list, but it doesn't have any code to deal with the second half. You might need an auxiliary predicate to deal with a length counter. Alternatively, you can consider using `append/3`. For `div(L, X, Y)` look at `append(X, Y, L)` and constrain the length of `X` or `Y`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could be just:

```
div(L, A, B) :-
    append(A, B, L),
    length(A, N),
    length(B, N).
```

Read as "appending list A and list B results in original list L, length of A is some value N and also length of B is the same value N".

Comment: Slightly shorter but otherwise the same: `div(L, A, B):- append(A, B, L), same_length(A, B), !.`

Comment: @WouterBeek *if* the OP is using SWI Prolog (they didn't specify). `same_length/2` is not an ISO predicate.

Comment: Maybe less iteration on `append` by pre-determining length of `A` and `B`: `div(L, A, B) :- length(L, N), Half is N div 2, length(A, Half), length(B, Half), append(A, B, L).`

Comment: @lurker Yes, but as it stated it's more relational and works even for queries like `div([1, 2 | X], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]).` Your version should be much faster, of course (O(N) vs O(1), I believe).

Comment: Or rather O(N^2) vs O(N).

Comment: With a list of 10 000 elements, Sergey's code : 30 006 inferences 0,140 CPU, lurker's code 5 015 inferences 0,000 CPU !

Comment: @lurker If we're going to the OP's homework anyway, then post that as an answer, I'd upvote it.

Comment: @SergeyDymchenko I like your solution (+1) and it is indeed more relational and elegant than my suggestion. I think the only failing relational case for the "more efficient" version occurs when `L` is unground but one of `A` or `B` are. It gives the correct solution, but will then spin forever on backtracking for more solutions. It could probably be modified to avoid that. Then it's just a trade between elegant versus efficient. Of course, code isn't always about efficiency. :)

Comment: @larsmans thanks. The homework issue on SO is a perpetual battle.

Answer (score 5):

Funny is this split which doesn't use length :

```
div(L, A, B) :-
    split(L, L, A, B).

split(B, [], [], B).

split([H|T], [_, _|T1], [H | T2], B) :-
    split(T, T1, T2, B).
```

For a list of 100 000 elements, it uses 50 001 inferences but 0,016 CPU, for the same list, lurker's code uses 50 015 inferences and 0,000 CPU.

Comment: Doh! You beat me by 14 inferences! I had a hunch there was a more elegant solution to this. Very nice (+1). :)

Comment: Yours is faster, what is the most usefull ?

Comment: So `split/4` uses the list itself as a doubly decremented "counter" to avoid using `length/2`.

Comment: "Most useful" would be hard to judge and would depend upon the application. In this case, we're probably splitting hairs. :) Coding is often a balance between simplicity (which enhances clarity and maintainability) and efficiency. I think your solution strikes a good balance.

Answer (score 2):

```
length(L) == length(L1)
```

is not how you compare lengths of lists in Prolog. It compares the ''terms'' `length(L)` and `length(L1)` without interpreting them, i.e. without calling any predicates. To compare lengths, do

```
length(L, N), length(L1, N)
```

If you fix that, your program should be closer to working.

Comment: I edited it but still didn't work :
div(L , L1 , L):- length(L , Q) , length(L1 , W) , Q =:= W.
div([ H | T ] , [ H | T1] , L2):- div(T , T1 , L2).

Comment: @user3100088 he said your program would be *closer* to working. Can you figure it out from there? Also, you don't need `length(L,Q), length(L1,W), Q =:= W.` It suffices to do, `length(L,N), length(L1,N)` as larsmans shows.

Answer (score 2):

I like Sergey's solution for its elegance and simplicity (+1). Here's another approach which is less elegant in favor of some further efficiency as it prunes the cases where `append` is queried. If either `A` or `B` are ground, then we let their length drive the process. Otherwise, we let the length of `L` drive it:

```
div(L, A, B) :-
    (   \+ground(A),
        \+ground(B)
    ->  length(L, N),
        HalfN is N div 2
    ;   true
    ),
    length(A, HalfN),
    length(B, HalfN),
    append(A, B, L).
```

And this will yield, for example:

```
| ?-  div2(L, A, B).

A = []
B = []
L = [] ? ;

A = [C]
B = [D]
L = [C,D] ? ;

A = [C,D]
B = [E,F]
L = [C,D,E,F] ?
...

| ?- div([1,2,3|T], A, B).

A = [1,2]
B = [3,C]
T = [C] ? ;

A = [1,2,3]
B = [C,D,E]
T = [C,D,E] ? ;
...

| ?- div(L, [1,2], B).

B = [A,C]
L = [1,2,A,C]

yes
| ?- div([1,2|T], [1,2], [3,4]).

T = [3,4]

yes
| ?-
```

*Etc.*

Answer (score 0):

It would just be,

```
div(L,L1,L2) :- length(L,Len), N is Len/2, split(L,L1,L2,N).
split([H|T],[H|L1],L2,N):- N1 is N-1, split(T,L1,L2,N1).
split(T,[],T,0).
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div(L, A, B) :-
append(A, B, L),
length(A, O),
length(B, N),
((O-1)=:=N;(O+1)=:=N;O=:=N),
!.
```

It's just this,  works with odd lenght :)