# Prolog Type Error

Tags: types, prolog

I'm working on a prolog algorithm that will perform a "swap" on a list.

Example:

Input: [1,2,3,4] -> Output: [3,4,1,2]
 Input: [1,2,3,4,5] -> Output: [4,5,3,1,2]

The first half and second half of the list swap places, if there is an odd number then the center element retains it's position. I have come up with an algorithm, but I am getting an error:

```
?- swap([1,2,3,4],L).
ERROR: length/2: Type error: `integer' expected, found `round(4/2)'
```

My code is as follows:

```
swap(L, S) :-
    length(L, Length),
    reverse(L, L2),
    mixing(L, Length, A),
    trim(L2, Length/2 , B),
    append(A,B,S).

trim(L,N,S) :-
    length(P,N),
    append(P,S,L).

mixing(L, Length, A) :-
    (  mod(Length, 2) == 0
    -> trim(L, round(Length/2), A)
    ;  trim(L, round(Length/2), A)
    ).
```

The problem is that in 'mixing' when I call trim (L, round(Length/2), A) the type is not integer? I understand that Length/2 is not an integer (most likely a float) and I thought round was equivalent to integer(expr) which rounds and transforms the data type to an integer. I also tried replacing round with the truncate(expr) and integer(expr), but I was receiving the same errors. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`round` is not a function, it's a predicate. I haven't looked at the rest of the code, but that line should be

```
round(Length/2, R), trim(L, R, A)
```

<strike>EDIT: BTW, you're overthinking it.</strike>

```
swap([], []).
swap([X], [X]).
swap([X, Y | A], [Y, X | B]) :- swap(A, B).
```

Comment: Your suggested implementation of `swap/2` doesn't do what the OP is wanting it to do.

Comment: I'm new to prolog in general so not super clear on all of the verbiage. Thank you for the clarification on the type problem. I'm still stuck in an imperative mindset of programming. It makes sense that I would need to use a predicate to get the value and then plug it back in. Also thanks for the code suggestion. Could you explain the last line?

Comment: I read it the same way you did when I read it the first time. :)

Comment: `round` is not a predicate. It is a function symbol! That is only evaluated with appropriate built-in predicates like `(is)/2` and the like.

Comment: @Amadan: Neither SICStus, nor SWI, nor GNU, nor ISO define `round/2` that way.

Comment: @false: I don't know how they define it, I am not that experienced in Prolog. I'm just saying that the above works on swipl.

Comment: @Amadan: `predicate_property(round(_,_),imported_from(quintus)).` holds in SWI. Thus, this is here for the purpose of backwards compatibility (way backwards into the 1980s).

Answer (score 2):

Prolog doesn't do inline expression evaluation. Thus, calls such as `trim(L2, Length/2 , B)` and `trim(L, round(Length/2), A)` will not work as you expect. Expressions are only evaluated in specific when using certain operators such as `is/2`, arithmetic comparisons, or their CLP(FD) counterparts. These expressions would need to be done as: `L is Length // 2, trim(L2, L, B)` and `R is round(Length/2), trim(L, R, A)` if done literally.

Your solution could be condensed, however, as follows.

```
swap(L, S) :-
    same_length(L, S),               % L and S are necessarily the same length
    length(L, N),
    M is N // 2,   % integer divide ; half the original list length
    length(Left, M),                 % Left is a list of half the length of L
                                     %   or half minus one if the length is odd
    (   (N mod 2) =:= 1              % If the original length is odd...
    ->  append(Left, [H|Right], L),  % then L is Left + [H|Right]
        append(Right, [H|Left], S)   %   So, S is Right + [H|Left]
    ;   append(Left, Right, L),      % otherwise, L is Left + Right
        append(Right, Left, S)       %   So, S is Right + Left
    ).
```

Comment: Could you the details of how this works? Specific questions: in "length(Left, M) where did Left come from? In the if/else block I'm assuming the "N /\ 1 =:= 1" is determining whether it's even or odd although I don't understand how. In the append statements, once again I'm uncertain where Left and Right are from, but what does the "[H | Right]" do/stand for?

Comment: @BrianSizemore `Left` is a variable I made up. If you call `length(Left, M)`, then Prolog will find solutions to that query, which is any list called `Length` which will have length `M`. If `M` is known, then Prolog will generate a list with unpopulated elements. Thus, it creates an empty list of length `M`. Check the manual for arithmetic operators, so yes, `N /\ 1` ands a 1 bit with the number. I could have used `mod`. The notation `[H|T]` for lists represents a list with first element (head) `H` and the rest of the list (tail) `T`. `=:=` compares results of expression evaluations.

Comment: @BrianSizemore I added some comments to the code and changed the `/\` to a `mod` for a little more clarity. In the Prolog interpreter, you can play with `append/3` and see what it does when you have variables instead of instantiated lists. Try, for example, `append(A, B, [a,b,c])` and see what it does. Also try, `length(L, 5)` to see what that does.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I've one upped your answer, but since Amadan answered the Type error question I'm going to leave him as the accepted answer. I appreciate all the help, you've given me a lot of insight into the proper mindset for programming in prolog!

Answer (score 0):

an idiomatic solution:

```
swap(L,S) :-
    %maplist(when_, [
    append([X,C,Y],L), (C=[];C=[_]), same_length(X,Y),
    reverse(X,U), reverse(Y,V), append([U,C,V],S)
    %])
    .

?- swap([1,2,3,4,5],S).
S = [2, 1, 3, 5, 4] ;
false.
```

it's not a true relation, since it hangs if called in mode `swap(-,+)`, but it behaves better after uncommenting the bracketing, and providing this snippet:

```
:- meta_predicate when_(0).
when_(P) :-
    strip_module(P,_,Q), Q =.. [_|As],
    or_list(As, Exp), display(Exp),
    when(Exp, P).

or_list([A], ground(A)) :- !.
or_list([A|As], (ground(A);Exp)) :- or_list(As, Exp).
```

*edit*

after @false' comments, I'm trying to explain the motivation of this answer. The requested swap/2 'function' seems to be an ideal candidate to showcase the peculiarity of Prolog data model, albeit the requested explanation (about proper syntactic usage of integer arithmetic applied to lists) is not even hinted here.

From the very start of Prolog we have available an unique mixing of relational *and* functional (recursive) tools, that could make little sense to a newbie. At least, it still surprises me... and I like this fact.

Now, functional logic programming, for instance [Curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry_%28programming_language%29), attempts a solution through 'narrowing'. From the linked page:

> Narrowing is useful because it allows a function to be treated as a relation: its value can be computed "in both directions"

Now, when_/1 it's a simple minded approach to the same problem. Down to earth, the swap/2 has been described as a function, but *could* be *implemented* as a relation ?

@false suggestion, adding `same_length(L,S)` as first goal, fixes the swap(-,+) mode, but loops on swap(-,-). The approach based on when_/1 instead reports the inability to ground the conjunction.

*edit*

Termination issues apart, my choice of goals *order* is really ineffective. Hinting this answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36831150/874024), occurred to me that a big efficiency gain (at least, for the mode swap(+,-)) can be obtained putting constraints first:

```
3 ?- numlist(1,100,L), time((append([X,C,Y],L), (C=[];C=[_]), same_length(X,Y), append([Y,C,X], S))). 
% 328,899 inferences, 0.125 CPU in 0.125 seconds (100% CPU, 2634422 Lips)
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9|...],
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9|...],
C = [],
Y = [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59|...],
S = [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59|...] 
.

4 ?- numlist(1,100,L), time(((C=[];C=[_]), same_length(X,Y), append([X,C,Y],L), append([Y,C,X], S))). 
% 3,273 inferences, 0.001 CPU in 0.001 seconds (100% CPU, 3210999 Lips)
```

Comment: When would swap/2 be a "true" relation? The case you mention is easily fixed by adding `same_length(L,S)` as first goal. Would it then by a true relation?

Comment: @false: too difficult, I was just hinting some alternatives, that OP could appreciate after the introductory lurker' comments. Of course, your fix is much better that spreading when/2 all over the conjunction. Do you think I should delete this answer, in case could just be confusing ? Thanks

Comment: It's OK as an answer. Still I want to know what you mean by true relation. After all, after the fix, `swap(L,[a|L])` still does not terminate although there is no solution (= finitely many solutions).

Comment: Well, I will try to improve when_/1 ASAP. Now I'm rebuilding SWi-Prolog... thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that is based upon a modification to [a predicate posted by @joel76](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22995777/splitting-a-list-into-two-lists-equal-in-length-in-prolog#answer-23012757) for splitting a list into two equal length lists. The modification I made enables the predicate to succeed with an odd-length list by including the "middle" list of 0 or 1 elements as an argument. It also uses `same_length` to constrain the arguments to avoid a termination issue for certain arguments. I included a simple implementation of `same_length/2` which not all Prologs have (it is included with SWI Prolog).

```
swap(L, S) :-
    same_length(L, S),
    div(L, Front, Middle, Back),     % L is divided into two halfs & middle
    append(Back, Middle, NewFront),  % S is Back + Middle + Front
    append(NewFront, Front, S).

% List L consists of Left + Middle + Right where Left and Right are equal length
%   and Middle has maximum length of 1
%
div(L, Left, Middle, Right) :-
    split(L, L, Left, Middle, Right).

split(L, [], [], [], L).
split([H|T], [_], [], [H], T).
split([H|T], [_, _|T1], [H|T2], M, Right) :-
    split(T, T1, T2, M, Right).

% same_length/2 is pre-defined in SWI Prolog and succeeds if the arguments
% are lists of equal length
%
same_length([], []).
same_length([_|Xs], [_|Ys]) :- same_length(Xs, Ys).
```

Comment: And, why not adopt your original version, too? This here will have some difficulties with `split/3`