# Swap beginning and end of lists in SWI-Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, swap

Okay, so I am trying to code in SWI-Prolog. I am supposed to swap the beginning and end of a list (breaking at the middle element). For even size lists I found it simple but for odd, I am having trouble.

```
    :- use_module(library(lists)).
    swap(L, Swapped) :-
        same_length(L, Swapped),
        length(L, S),
        (   mod(S, 2) =:= 0 
        ->  divi(L, A, B)
        ;   nth1(S, L, X, R),
            divi(R, A, Las),
            append(Las, X, B)
        ),
        append(B, A, Swapped).


    divi(L, A, B) :- 
        length(L, N), 
        Half is N div 2, 
        length(A, Half), 
        length(B, Half), 
        append(A, B, L).
```

*EDIT - I used the nth1 for deleting the middle element to try and bring it to an even sized list and swapping that way but my output is always false.

Here is an example of how i input it

```
?-swap([1,2,3,4],Swapped).
```

changing the numbers and size of list are necessary when testing.

Comment: Thank you @lurker I am really new to Prolog

Comment: Prolog is a language you need to learn to think differently with. Have a look at the different answers in that link to learn a couple of techniques and patterns. I think that would be much more beneficial than trying to get your code to work, which is the result of trying to use Prolog as an imperative language (which is what most beginners do).

Comment: @lurker I know what you mean by linking me to the other answers, but could you explain why I am getting only "false" as an output when I use an odd list and I get the correct swapped list when the query has an even list? I will continue to look further into the other solutions to better my knowledge.

Comment: Try running it with an odd sized list, false should be the output. I was wondering why it was only giving false rather than the type error from the other problem . @lurker

Comment: `nth1(S, L, X, R),` yields an *element* `X`. Later you call `append(Las, X, B)` which attempts to say that `B` is the list `Las` appended to a non-list  `X`. You can't append an element that way. Try `append(Las, [X], B).`

Comment: in SWI, you can trick [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36760627/874024) to get one liner solution: try `?- L=[y,o,u,r,d,a,t,a], append([X,C,Y],L), (C=[];C=[_]), same_length(X,Y), append([Y,C,X], S).`